# Custom table view cells show up blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a regular view controller (not a table view controller) and on that view I have a tableview. My table view cells are custom and I just made them through storyboards (didn't do anything in the code) but when I run my application, the tableview is blank. Any ideas as to why tho is happening to me? I have looked at other things on here but all of these other scenarios have to do with the person using an NSArray to fill out the tableview in the code, but mine is custom so I am not doing that. Thanks for any help. And before you mark this duplicate, please actually read this.
my code is as follows:

```
@interface TTViewController ()
{
    NSArray *messageComponents;
}

@end

@implementation TTViewController
@synthesize dateTimePicker, messageSetupTableView;


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.title = @"Message Setup";

        messageComponents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Recipient",@"Message", @"Date",@"haha", nil];


        messageSetupTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        messageSetupTableView.alpha = 0.9;

    }
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView{

        return [messageComponents count];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableVew numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return 1;
    }

    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            }
        }

        // Configure the cell.

        cell.textLabel.text = [messageComponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[messageComponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIColor *selectedColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        UIView *myBackgroundColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [myBackgroundColor setBackgroundColor:selectedColor];

        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:myBackgroundColor];

        return cell;
```

I want my table view to have a `date picker in one section`, a `textview` in the other, and `a button and a few text fields` in the other. Thanks

Comment: please paste code you have tried so far.

Comment: I just posted some code in my question

Comment: [quickdialog](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/quickdialog) ,very good example for requirement like you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. First make sure that `UITableView`'s **delegate** and **datasource** are mapped or not either from `IB` or `programmatically`.
2. Put a break point on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate function and see if it comes in this functions, and make sure you are using this function to create your custom cells.
3. Double check your have at least one row in your `tableView` using something similar:

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return 5;   // for test pass value 5 so tableView should aware to display 5 rows.
   }
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The function signature doesn't actually include the parameter names, you can use aTableView, tableView, table, whatever, so long as the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: parts match up.

Comment: Correct, i haven't noticed that the change is in param name instead of the actually recognized part. I believe that is why we mention like @selector(function1:withsecondArgument:) instead of mentioning the param names.